# AppUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() returns UPDATE_AVAILABLE on a Pixel 6 but returns UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE on multiple Samsung devices

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-update

I am trying to use the AppUpdateManager class to check to see if an update is available, however I am seeing different results depending on what type of Android device that I use.  When I make the call with a Pixel 6 Pro, it returns an update is available, but when I tried the same code on a couple of Samsung devices, it returns not available.  Below is a sample of the code that I am using.  Does anyone have an idea of why this behavior might happen between devices?

```
fun checkForUpdates(activity: Activity) {
    val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(activity)
    
    appUpdateManager?.appUpdateInfo.addOnSuccessListener {
        val updateAvailability = it.updateAvailbility()

        // Pixel 6 Pro -> Returns UPDATE_AVAILABLE
        // Samsung Galaxy S21 -> Returns UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE

    }
}
```

I would expect any device I try to return the same value when I do an update check.

Comment: Did you create Samsung device with an api with google play services ? Maybe it is the problem

Comment: I'm testing with real devices that have the latest version of google play services

Comment: Then I recommend you to use Android Studio debugger. Add breakpoints to availability checker method of appUpdateManager?.appUpdateInfo class and to see why it returns UPDATE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Comment: I've tested on multiple Pixel, One plus, and Samsung devices. it seems only Samsung has the issue.